# WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR (Python Anaconda en VSCode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I installed anaconda and created a virtual environment with mediapipe to use in VSCode. When executing code I get the following message:

> WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
> W20210623 16:54:19.951897 26336 tflite_model_loader.cc:32] Trying to
> resolve path manually as GetResourceContents failed: ; Can't find
> file: mediapipe/modules/face_detection/face_detection_front.tflite
> INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.

Message:
[image]

The result runs successfully but that message causes me concern

It should be clarified that I also opened the PromptAnaconda and the same message appears and I selected the Anaconda Python interpreter in VSCode

The code is this:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

mp_face_detection = mp.solutions.face_detection
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

with mp_face_detection.FaceDetection(
     min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_detection:
     image = cv2.imread("cara.jpg")
     cv2.imshow("Image", image)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks for your answers and I hope you can help me.

***I use google translator, sorry if it is wrongly translated***

Comment: Hey, I am facing this same issue when using mediapipe, did you manage to find any solution?

Comment: Related:
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2094
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2119
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2354
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3017
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3672